# What's an TASK_ACTION_COM_HANDLER and how to use it?

Tags: c, winapi

I was looking into task scheduler API and I've found `TASK_ACTION_COM_HANDLER` at [IActionCollection_Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-iactioncollection-create) - I was wondering what it does and if possible some sample usage.

Comment: Just a bit more looking would show you the  [IComHandlerAction interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-icomhandleraction)

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I already know that

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions read it again more carefully, it gives you the answer: "*COM handlers must implement the ITaskHandler interface for the Task Scheduler to start and stop the handler.*" `IComHandlerAction` is the link you give to `IActionCollection` to tell it which TaskHandler to execute. Create a COM object that implements `ITaskHandler`, give its CLSID to `IComHandlerAction`, and give that action to `IActionCollection`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah but how to create an COM object in C?

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions that is a completely different question, and one that can be answered by MSDN. But why are you using C? It is not impossible to work with COM in C, but it is much easier in C++ instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau See you can't find one. I didn't saw you edit - sorry. I prefer C because it's much nicer language. For example you don't need to do unnecessary casts all the time.